# Extract frames from base64 encoded text file (video)

Tags: python-3.x, base64

I encoded a video file to a text file using base64:

```
import base64



with open("VIDEO_FILE.mp4", "rb") as videoFile:
    text = base64.b64encode(videoFile.read())
    
    file = open("TEXT_FILE.txt", "wb") 
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
```

Now, I would like to read the file and extract the base64 string for a specific frame. Is this possible? How are the frames separated in the text file?

Comment: Base64 doesn't have a specific structure, it just encodes the original bytes into the base64 character set in which each character represents 6 bits of the original data. So basically you would need to decode the data to find the frame or do it before you encode it. The real question is how to find a certain frame in mp4 format  That's something you might find an anawer for using google.

Comment: @jps Okay, I see, so there is no way to extract the string that makes the frame from the whole text.

Comment: Right, not from the string. But from the original data.